# Double ampersand in C++. (First declaration on func params, second - before the variables)

Tags: c++11

Sorry for my low level of English.
I have one question.

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, PbxCfgHeader &info)
{
    out.writeRawData((char*)&info, sizeof(info));
    return out;
}
```

In the code above, a record `(char*)&info` equivalent `T &&`? 
Thank you

Comment: R-value reference, introduced in C++11.

Comment: Perhaps you would like http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ better?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Use `[ru.so]` for a quick link to [ru.so].

Comment: `char*` is a pointer to `char` - where did you get `T&&` from in this context?

Answer (score 2):

The `&` in the parameter list (or in any declaration) is unrelated to the use of `&` in expressions. (The syntax is unfortunate.)

In a declaration `&foo` means "I'm declaring `foo` as a reference" (i.e. an alias for another variable).

In an expression `&foo` means "I'm taking the address of `foo`" (i.e. the result is a pointer to `foo`).

The two are very different, and they don't "stack". `&info` in your code does not have type `PbxCfgHeader &&` (and that double `&&` is yet another thing called an r-value reference).